# Ajax TruClient script running error MERR-205177

Tags: ajax, loadrunner, truclient

I create a script with Ajax TruClient protocol, debugged it until it perfectly runs in VUgen.

After that I include the script into .XML list for ContinuousIntegration process. It can run several days successfully.
And one day it starts to fail, its mdrv<...>.

log looks like:

```
t=00600869ms: Error -205177: Internal Error - Failed to create _sBrowserLoader [MsgId: MERR-205177] [MsgId: MERR-205177]
Warning: Extension LrWeb2Replay reports error -1 on call to function ExtPerProcessInitialize [MsgId: MWAR-10485]
Error: Thread Context: Call to service of the driver failed, reason - thread context wasn't initialized on this thread. [MsgId: MERR-10176]
```

Now I have already several such failed scripts and I cannot understand what's wrong.

As log-file contains "Failed to create _sBrowserLoader", so maybe I should kill the FF process before to start next the Ajax TruClient script?
What could be the reason?
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the problem as follows:

1. kill mdrv-process that hangs starting with the date of the first
   script FAIL;
2. in the script folder delete all temporary *.ci
       files, excluding script_name.ci file.

And script starts to run succesfully again.

The problem isn't resolved, as I still don't know the reason of mdrv hanging.
But thats enough at the moment.